# Changing calling convention in gcc/g++ abi

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention, abi

How could I enforce gcc/g++ to not use registers but only stack in x86_64
to pass arguments to functions,
like it was in 32-bit version
(and possibly take the function result this way).
I know it breaks official ABI and both the caller side and the called side
must be compiled this way so it works. I don't care if push/pop or mov/sub way
is used. I expect there should be a flag to compiler that could enforce it
but I couldn't find it.

Comment: As a workaround if it's your own code you could pass arguments in a struct which is more than 32 bytes as those are passed on the stack according to the sysv abi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can't without hacking GCC's source code.

There is no standard x86-64 calling convention that uses inefficient stack args.

GCC only knows how to use standard calling conventions, in this case x86-64 SysV and MS Windows fastcall and vectorcall.  (e.g. `__attribute__((ms_abi))` or `vectorcall`).  Normally nobody wants this; MS's calling convention is already friendly enough for wrappers or variadic functions.  You can use that for some functions (controlled by `__attribute__`) even when compiling for Linux, MacOS, *BSD, etc., if that helps.  Hard to imagine a use-case for pure stack args.

---

GCC lets you specify a register as fixed (never touched by GCC, like `-ffixed-rdi`), call-clobbered, or call-preserved.  **But using those with arg-passing registers just creates wrong code, not what you want.**

e.g.

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c);

void caller(int x) {
    foo(1,2,3);
    //foo(4,x,6);
}
```

[compiled by gcc9.2 `-O3 -fcall-saved-rdi`](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int+foo(int+a,+int+b,+int+c)%3B%0A%0Avoid+caller(int+x)+%7B%0A++++foo(1,2,3)%3B%0A++++//foo(4,x,6)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:48.04846017120344,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:44.99995238049887,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-fcall-saved-rdi',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:35.28487316212991,l:'4',m:55.504581264111465,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang900,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-fverbose-asm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+9.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:44.495418735888535,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:55.000047619501146,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

```
caller:
        push    rdi
        mov     edx, 3
        mov     esi, 2
        pop     rdi
        jmp     foo
```

It saves/restores RDI but doesn't put a `1` in it before calling `foo`.

And it doesn't leave RDI out of the arg-passing sequence and bump other args later.  (I was thinking you might be able to invent a calling convention where all the arg-passing registers were `fixed` or `call-saved`, maybe getting GCC to fall back to stack args.  But nope.)

Comment: It appears GCC doesn't support vectorcall yet: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89485 Seems to work in clang though.